# Redirect to new page after jquery uploads done

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get this jquery tool to work with my website for file uploads: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and I have it working for the most part.  The only issue I am having is trying to find a place where I can make it redirect to a new page to display the results of the upload instead of displaying them on the same page.  I want to have the option for the users to do things with the images and files they just uploaded, and a new page makes more sense for this than using the same page over and over and over again...

Can anyone tell me from experience of understanding something in the documentation/code that I didn't grasp on how I can do this?  Thanks :)  Please note that i want the page to be redirected at the end of ALL of the uploads and not after the first if there are four more.  I will be storing the data in a PHP session to access on the next page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be like this (in this case redirecting to *http://stackoverflow.com*):

```html
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadstop', function (e) {/* ... */});

});
</script>
```

Check out the [docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options).

Comment: I tried using that already, done seems to be called after each file is uploaded, not after all of them have been uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // ... additional parameters
        complete: function (e, data) {
            window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: complete is a deprecated function from v4

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has an events called `onComplete` and `onCompleteAll`. Use them.

Comment: onCompeteAll is an outdated function for an older version of this plugin