# Blueimp file upload script redirects after first uploaded file

Tags: jquery, ajax, blueimp

Blueimp Jquery file upload script. I need to reload page when the ajax finishes uploading files. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555429/redirect-to-new-page-after-jquery-uploads-done) and added:

```
complete: function (e, data) {
            window.location = "/result.php";
        }
```

Unfortunately, the script redirects when the first file is uploaded and not when all files finish uploading. What I am doung wrong? Below is my script.

```
<script>
var defaultthumbnail = '<img class="thumb" src="/upload1.png">';
$(function () {
var formData = $('#fileupload').serializeArray();
'use strict';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
url:'//static.example.com',

complete: function (e, data) {
window.location = "/result.php";
}

});


$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/i,
autoUpload:true,
maxNumberOfFiles:100,
maxFileSize:10000000,

disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
});
if ($.support.cors) {
$.ajax({
url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
type: 'HEAD'
}).fail(function () {
$('<div class="warning"/>')
.text('error')
.appendTo('#fileupload');
});
} 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the callback [stop](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#stop) it will help you

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: '//static.example.com',

    stop: function (e) {
        console.log('Uploads finished');
        window.location = "/result.php";
    }

});
```